# Trying to make a simple JS slideshow. Doesnt work. Buttons dont change div bg color and img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I was trying to make a simple JS slideshow. But it does not work.

The previmg() is not made yet, I will do that when the problem is solved. I have div dots to show which img im on two arrows on each sides to switch between photos.

It should look like:

```
____________________________________________
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                  IMAGE                   |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|__________________________________________|
| _________  ___    ___   ___    _______   |
| | //___ | |   |  |   | |   |  | ___\\ |  |  
| |_\\____| |___|  |___| |___|  |____//_|  |  
|__________________________________________|
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function nextimg(){
                if(document.getElementById('oneB').style.backgroundColor == black){
                    document.getElementById('oneB').style.backgroundColor=white;
                    document.getElementById('twoB').style.backgroundColor = black;
                    document.getElementById('img').src = "img/img_build.png";
                }
                else if(document.getElementById('twoB').style.backgroundColor == black){
                    document.getElementById('twoB').style.backgroundColor=white;
                    document.getElementById('threeB').style.backgroundColor = black;
                    document.getElementById('img').src = "img/img_program.png";
                }
                else if(document.getElementById('threeB').style.backgroundColor == black){
                    document.getElementById('threeB').style.backgroundColor=white;
                    document.getElementById('fourB').style.backgroundColor = black;
                    document.getElementById('img').src = "img/img_rubix.png";
                }
                else if(document.getElementById('fourB').style.backgroundColor == black){
                    document.getElementById('fourB').style.backgroundColor=white;
                    document.getElementById('oneB').style.backgroundColor = black;
                    document.getElementById('img').src = "img/img_battle.png";
                }
            }
</script>

<div class="slide">
                <image name="img" src="img/img_battle.png" class="image"/>
                <div class="navibar">
                    <button onclick="previmg();" style="font-size:14pt;color:white;width:40px;margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:5px;float:left;background-color:gray;border:2px solid gray;border-radius:2px;"><img style="height:20px;width:20px" src="img/arrow-left.png"/></button>
                    <div id="oneB" class="blip" style="background-color:black"></div>
                    <div id="twoB" class="blip"></div>
                    <div id="threeB" class="blip"></div>
                    <div id="fourB" class="blip"></div>
                    <button onclick="nextimg();" style="font-size:14pt;color:white;width:40px;margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:5px;float:left;background-color:gray;border:2px solid gray;border-radius:2px;"><img style="height:20px;width:20px" src="img/arrow-right.png"/></button>
              </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) avoids usings inlines styles. [Why use css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS) 2) Instead of querying the `DOM` every time using `getElementBy..`, keep a reference variable. So that your code will be readable (*along with slight performance improvements*)....

Comment: The value returned by `style.backgroundColor` is a string, you are comparing with variable names which are undefined. Thus none of your if statements execute.

Comment: Actually what are you trying to achieve by changing attributes of `oneB`, `twoB` etc..? currently they have `0` height and hence not visible. The images and `prev/next` are outside of them anyways...